# Adjusting load voltage with a potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer

I'm reading the book "Practical Electronics for Inventors, 4th Ed", and I find it great, but I'm stuck on this (seemingly straightforward) section on page 321:

[image]

First off, the values in the "Adjusting Load Current" graph are wrong.
As the author wrote, when a-to-b Resistance is 10kΩ, `V-load` is 5V, not 1V, and `I-load` is 0.5mA, not 0.1mA.

What bothers me, however, is the graph for the "Adjusting Load Voltage" circuit.
Wrong values in the graph, ok.
**But how come `I-load` doesn't follow the same curve as `V-load`?**

It's a DC circuit with plain resistors.
When a-to-b Resistance is 5kΩ, `V-load` is 4V, so `I-load` becomes 0.4mA (I = V/R = 4V/10kΩ = 0.4mA).
When a-to-b Resistance is 1kΩ, `V-load` is 8.26V, so `I-load` becomes 0.826mA (I = V/R = 8.26V/10kΩ = 0.826mA).

Again, it might have been an error with the graph, but the author explicitly points out the difference:

> Adjusting load current:
> Notice in the graph that the load current follows a curve similar to that of the voltage.
> ...
> Adjusting load voltage:
> Notice that in the graph, the load current doesn’t fall as quickly as in the previous configuration. In fact, from 0 to 5 kΩ the current falls about only 1/10 its maximum value. However, from 5 kΩ on, the drop grows significantly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Consider the pot as two separate resistors that sum to 10k. The top circuit is trivial. The bottom is like a resistor in series with 2 parallel resistors, one being the load.

Comment: You are not missing anything here.

Comment: @MOSFET Exactly, but that doesn't answer my question: why doesn't `I-load` follow the same curve as `V-load`? If `I=V/R` and `R` is constant, `I` and `V` should follow the same curve.

Comment: @Loris Source impedance of the pot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a possibly a mess in terminology done by the Author. Precisely he seems to mess the input current of the network, say
$$
I_\textsf{IN} =\frac{V_\textsf{IN}}{R_\textsf{IN}},
$$
with the true load current, i.e.
$$
I_\textsf{load} =\frac{V_\textsf{load}}{R_\textsf{load}}.
$$
In the first configuration, the load resistor is series connected to the a-to-b section of the potentiometer, thus invariably \$I_\textsf{IN}=I_\textsf{load}\$.
In the second configuration the potentiometer and the resistor are not connected in series thus it is always \$I_\textsf{IN}\neq I_\textsf{load}\$.

However \$I_\textsf{load}\$  is always proportional to \$V_\textsf{load}\$.

Comment: I agree, the authors made a right mess of that. There's no \$I_{LOAD}\$ annotated anywhere in their schematics, so you have to guess. And if you guessed that it's the current through \$R_{LOAD}\$, which would make perfect sense, the maths, and lower graph don't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

The study of the circuit is simple: you just need to know how to treat the potentiometer or trimmer, that is, rotating the trimmer screw corresponds the variable k between zero and one:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I think you made the topic more complex than it has to be, without really answering my question. Or perhaps I don't see how you did. Why doesn't `I-load` follow the same curve as `V-load`?

Comment: The trend of the current and the voltage is the same, only that the current is given by the voltage divided by the resistance, so the graphs cannot coincide.